# Which mathematician has argued that we should move from "set" to "order"?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, order-theory, foundations, mathematicians

I recall reading (on this very site, in fact) that there is a mathematician whom argues that we ought to switch from "set" to "order" in the foundations, so as to "recover duality" or some such.

Does anyone know who this is? And/or where they've argued this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Baez once argued that $0$-categories should be preorders rather than sets, but the argument was based on higher category theory. Specifically, that the hierarchy of categories should start at $-2$, and goes:

- There is just one $(-2)$ category.
- $(-1)$ categories are equivalent to truth values -- a $(-1)$ category has objects, and the homsets are $(-2)$-categories. Therefore either a $(-1)$ category is empty, or it is non-empty and all objects are isomorphic.
- $0$ categories should be equivalent to preorders -- a $0$ category would have objects, and the homsets are $(-1)$-categories: i.e. truth values. Working out what the composition law should mean amounts to making the value of $\hom(X,Y)$ mean the truth of $X \leq Y$ where $\leq$ is a preorder.

Then, we recover sets as being analogous to groupoids: they are preorders whose arrows are all isomorphisms. Actually, this gives setoids -- sets with an equivalence relation -- but setoids are equivalent to sets.

(IMO, the rationale that preorders are a better basic notion that set is not implausible even without trying to imagine $(-2)$- and $(-1)$-categories. And I definitely think setoid is a better basic notion than set)

I don't recall him saying anything about duality, though, so this may have nothing to do with what you're remembering.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Also, why do you think setoid is a better basic notion than set? The way I see, a set is just a *weak* setoid; i.e. a setoid up to equivalence.

Comment: @user18921: Because people use setoids *in practice*. e.g. consider quotient rings, like $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$, the field of $p$ elements. When pressed, most people will say it is a set of equivalence classes, or maybe a set of representatives for equivalence classes. But in practice, people almost never use that: they always use ordinary *integers* for the elements of this ring (and any integer can be used), and write equivalences rather than equations.

Comment: ... also, IMO it's even more far reaching than that. e.g. in the language of integer arithmetic, `1+2` is an integer, and so is `3`. I think it's a mildly more accurate description of mathematics to say that `1+2` and `3` are equivalent elements of the integers, than to say `1+2` *is* `3`.

Comment: There's also an idea floating around that I haven't really grokked: that up to equivalence, equality *is* equivalence. I've been growing into the idea that equality is not talking about what something *is*, but instead is talking about the point where we stop acknowledging the distinction between equivalent things.

Comment: Interesting arguments. I'd like to try playing devil's advocate, though, if you're interested.

Comment: I don't mind. But for tonight I don't expect to be on much longer.